# applicationContext.xml не подсвечивается как контекст в IntelijIdea?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

У меня простое тестовое spring-приложение.
Почему файл applicationContext.xml не подсвечивается как контекст спринга(подсветка синтаксиса, автоподстановка), а отображается как обычный файл xml?

Открываю с помощью indelij Idea.

Comment: indelij Idea community?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor не, ultimate

Comment: а в модулях проекта спринг подключен?